# What does "^[" represent?

Tags: highlighting, characters, escape

I wrote a terminal output to a plain text file and opened it in Emacs, and I see "^[" here and there. I'd like to change it to tabs in terminal before writing its output to the file, but I don't know how to refer to them. What does "^[" represent?

They have "[1m" or "[4m" right after them.

Answer (score 1):

`^[` is the [ASCII escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character), aka `ESC`. It is:

- octal: `\033`
- hexadecimal: `\x1B` or `^[`
- decimal: `27`

The color codes (and other control codes) you mention each begin with the ASCII escape character.

Answer (score 1):

Characters represented with `^` followed by another character (an uppercase letter or one of `@[\]^_?`), with both characters in a different color (depending on the color scheme), are [control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character). `^[` is the [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#ASCII_escape_character). You can get more information by pressing `C-x =` (`what-cursor-position`) while the cursor is on the character and even more information with `C-u C-x =`.

Here, in output meant for a terminal, the escape character starts an [escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence), specifically an [ANSI escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_sequences) which is how the application tells the terminal to do something other than “display this character at the cursor location and move one position to the right”. Specifically, `^[[…m` (also known as “CSI … m” because the two-character sequence `^[[` is known as [CSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_sequences#CSI_codes)) change the text attributes for subsequet output. `^[[1m` turns bold on, `^[[4m` turns underline on, and `^[[0m` turns all attributes off.

Changing those characters to tabs makes no sense whatsoever.

You can use [this script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14684/removing-control-chars-including-console-codes-colours-from-script-output/14707#14707) to remove most terminal escape sequences.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that they were color codes in Terminal. I managed to get rid of them by

```
sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g"
```

http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3584/remove-color-codes-special-characters-with-sed